# Problem on finding sequence of Taq polymerase

Tags: molecular-biology, bioinformatics

As i know, Taq Polymerase can be found in Thermus aquaticus, so i do a search for protein list of Thermus aquaticus and have this : http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genome/proteins/1724?project_id=55053 . After filter for 'polymerase' i found a lot of protein named polymerase :

- DNA polymerase beta domain protein region
- DNA polymerase I
- DNA polymerase III, alpha subunit
- DNA polymerase III, beta subunit
- DNA polymerase III, delta subunit
- DNA-directed DNA polymerase
  -.....

I don't know what they mean and which is the protein i'm looking for ?

---

After click on one of them i have the sequence not in A-T-G-X format :

ORIGIN
        1 msgvdallll gvelsraiit aysvyaivli lggflarlpt rweervealg gsfylagvil
       61 wryyaggday dldlflrasg mallvlprlv rvvlreyggg r

What does it mean and how to working with it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the paper here](http://talon.niagara.edu/~mgallo/391s08web/papers/taq-isolation.pdf) "Taq polymerase" is the DNA polymerase I from *Thermus aquaticus*. (Incidentally the paper has the complete sequence of the gene in question.)

You can find a protein sequence entry at NCBI [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/507891?report=genbank&log%24=protalign&blast_rank=9&RID=Y334H3GW014). This shows the sequence of amino acids in the protein, not the DNA sequence of the gene. Several lines from the top you will see:

> DBSOURCE    locus TTHDNAP accession D32013.1

with the last word highlighted as a link. Follow that link to the DNA sequence. That entry includes the line:

> CDS             1..2499

which tells you that the initiator ATG of the gene is right at the start of the sequence shown, but that the 3026 bp sequence includes a lot of downstream DNA. If you click on CDS on that line it will highlight the coding sequence in the DNA.

A very cursory comparison of this sequence with the one in the paper that I linked to suggests that this is the same gene.

Answer (score 0):

Thank Alan Boyd so much, below is the answer for these protein code mean:

```
    A  alanine               P  proline       
    B  aspartate/asparagine  Q  glutamine      
    C  cystine               R  arginine      
    D  aspartate             S  serine      
    E  glutamate             T  threonine      
    F  phenylalanine         U  selenocysteine      
    G  glycine               V  valine        
    H  histidine             W  tryptophan        
    I  isoleucine            Y  tyrosine
    K  lysine                Z  glutamate/glutamine
    L  leucine               X  any
    M  methionine            *  translation stop
    N  asparagine            -  gap of indeterminate length
```

Source from NCBI : http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/BLAST/blastcgihelp.shtml